# Prevent or delete duplicates in textscraper?

Tags: ruby, search, duplicates, scraper

I have a code that parses through text files in a folder, and saves a predefined number of words around certain search words.

For example, it looks for words such as "date" and "year". If it finds both in the same sentence it will save the sentence twice. Furthermore, if it finds the same word used a few times in a sentence, it will also save it multiple times.

This way the scraper saves an enormous amount of unnecessary duplicate text.

I see two possible solutions:

1. If the next search-match is in the padding, in the group of words, of the previous one, it will not be saved.
2. If a group of, say, seven words of the search match is also part of the preceding group it will not be saved/deleted.

Everything I've tried has utterly failed thusfar:

```
#helper
def indices text, index, word
    padding = 200
    bottom_i = index - padding < 0 ? 0 : index - padding
    top_i = index + word.length + padding > text.length ? text.length : index +         word.length + padding
    return bottom_i, top_i
end

#script
base_text = File.open("base.txt", 'w')
Dir::mkdir("summaries") unless File.exists?("summaries")
Dir.chdir("summaries")

Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |textfile|
    whole_file = File.open(textfile, 'r').read
    puts "Currently summarizing " + textfile + "..."
    curr_i = 0
    str = nil
    whole_file.scan(Regexp.union(/firstword/, /secondword/).each do |match|
      if i_match = whole_file.index(match, curr_i)
        top_bottom = indices(whole_file, i_match, match)
        base_text.puts(whole_file[top_bottom[0]..top_bottom[1]] + " : " +         File.path(textfile))
        curr_i += i_match                     
      end
    end
    puts "Done summarizing " + textfile + "."
end
base_text.close
```

Comment: You need to work on your code style. Use blocks with your `File.open` and `Dir.chdir`. Instead of `File.open(...).read` just `File.read(...)`. `Regexp.union` as you are using it will match inside words which is probably not what you want. Embed that inside another regex like `/\b(?:#{Regexp.union(...)})\b/` to match on word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably something better than:

```
whole_file.scan(Regexp.union(/firstword/, /secondword/).each do |match|
  if i_match = whole_file.index(match, curr_i)
    top_bottom = indices(whole_file, i_match, match)
    base_text.puts(whole_file[top_bottom[0]..top_bottom[1]] + " : " +         File.path(textfile))
    curr_i += i_match + 50                     
  end        
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something where you keep track of what you're looking for:

```
search_words = %w( year date etc )
```

And then downcase the search string, and start an index.

```
def summarize(str)
  search_str = str.downcase
  ind = 0
```

Then find the smallest index offset of your search words in the search_str, and remove everything up to (ind + offset - delta), go up to (ind + delta) into matches, and continue in the while loop. Something like:

```
  matches = []
  while (offset = search_words.map{|w| search_str.index w }.min)
    ind += offset
    matches.push str[ind - delta, delta * 2]
    search_str = search_str[offset + delta, ]
  end
  matches
end
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with these methods. So what exactly does this do? So this is a complete alternative to my scraper, and deletes, for every text, what if finds WITHIN the offset of a preceding find?.. Or??